# How do I make this button link to a URL? Bootstrap 4

Tags: url, button, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make this button, link to a specific URL but I don't know where to add it in the code of the button, I'm using bootstrap 4.3, thank you!

**Code**

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
  <i class="fas fa-align-right text-light"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick="location.href='{url goes here}'"` to your button tag.

**Working example**

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="location.href='https://stackoverflow.com'"> 
  <i class="fas fa-align-right text-light"></i> Go to Stackoverflow
</button>
```